value of bevel shape when inside
We usually do a bevel shape=0.5 when we want to get a round (eleptic) angle.
If we want to create an angle inward rather than outward - what should the shape value be? Please, watch the animation


It seems you have figured it out on the GIF? :D If you zoom in a lot in orthographic view you can adjust the value quite precisely...

The Shape value of 1 gives a rectangular convex corner (as if it was not beveled at all), 0.5 is a quarter of a  circle, 0.25 is a straight line and everything below is a concave (inward) shape. Unfortunately I have no idea how the shape factor relates to an actual superellipse equation. In the specific case that semi-axes are both 1, the equation would be $\left|{x}\right|^n+\left|{y}\right|^n=1$ with $n$ defining the shape. But this would mean $n$ has to be 2 for a circle and 1 for straight edges. An "inverse circle arc" would require a shape value of approx. 0.56 - in the real equation.

Now while shape values of 2 and 1 for circle arc and straight line seem to be simply divided by 4 to find their equivalent in the Bevel tool's Shape value, this is no longer true for the "inverted" circle arc, because 0.56 / 4 = 0.14, but if you use this for the bevel shape it would still be too much. The closest to the desired result you will get wirh a Shape value around 0.0858 and I have no idea how this relates to the superellipse equation.

Short answer
My best results from a single number come from the expression pow(1-sqrt(.5), 2), which can be directly entered but evaluates to approximately 0.085786.
Long answer
I came across your question while fighting with something similar, in my case trying to find a circular superellipse profile parameter for a vertex bevel. I believe the results to be related, as the bevel vertex appears to be the inverse of the edge bevel with the same profile parameter.
After digging through the source code and extensive experimentation with various conversion formulae for the parameter, I believe I've found some clues regarding the value Gordon Brinkmann suggested, although unfortunately not the clearest of answers.
As they noted, the superellipse equation is typically considered to be
$$|x|^{n}+|y|^{n}=1$$
With $n$ as the profile parameter determining its sharpness and concavity. In this form, $n$ ranges from 0 to $\infty$. However, Blender's input ranges from 0 to 1, with inverted and distorted results, meaning there's some kind of conversion formula being applied before the input parameter is used in the algorithm. Unfortunately, the code isn't terribly clear here. Perhaps someone else can find the exact formula, but for now the most I was able to glean was the function:
$$-\log_2{\sqrt{x}}$$
Which matches three of the four distinct points I was able to map definitively from the Blender parameter to the mathematical parameter:
Blender - Mathematical - Rough formula
$$\begin{matrix}
0 & \infty & \infty \\
-\log_2{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}} & 2 & \sim1.77 \\
0.25 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}$$
I'll update this if I find a better formula. Until then, this would suggest that the parameter you're looking for is $\frac{1}{16}$, which it most certainly is not. I believe it involves a $-\log_2$, a square root, an inversion, and one minus something. What those somethings are is unclear.
Ultimately the necessary parameter relates to whatever this conversion formula is more than it does to the superellipse equation, but I'm not yet precisely sure how. Simply trying permutations of these operations is where I found a seemingly-related formula which appears to produce an extremely close answer. As evidence, this is what my operation resulted in:


For those who are unsatisfied with this answer (as am I) you may turn to Bézier curve approximations of circles using the custom profile menu.
Based on this answer: Approximating circles with Bézier curves
You can manipulate the coordinates of the handle points to a distance of (4/3)*tan(pi/8) from the two corresponding control points. My result in the following image:

Until I can uncover anything else, happy Blendering!
